# Webform Query Confirmation Email Tokens Not Passing

Tags: webforms

Has anyone else encountered this behavior? I can pass static tokens but not values using [current-page:query:?] in the Webform 8 Confirmation URL. I'm trying to append an email address.

If I use:
?email=[current-page:query:email]  it returns 
?email=?e=%5Bcurrent-page%3Aquery%3Aemail%5D

but 
?email=[site:mail] returns 
?email=correctemail%40email.com

I can pass any static variables, but not from the current query.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The documentation suggests [current-page:query:email] but the working token is [webform_submission:values:email:urlencode]